# Extension not installs it's database tables

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

I am installing extension to magento ("AheadWorks RMA"). But module not showing up on backend or frontend. And there are no any tables that should be there for this extension. What should I do to fix that to make this module work? Is it okay to copy/paste queries from sql folder files to database?

Comment: no copy paste query is not standard work as defined in magento standard.

Comment: Please clear all cash in admin side & check again & also cross check core_resource table any version entry this module or not

Comment: @abdul , core_resource has not any records for this module

Comment: your cash enable or disable?

Comment: disable and I refresh it and delete folder "cache"

Comment: now check system -> Configuration : Advanced and open section and see you module there or not

Comment: @Abdul, yes it is there

Comment: is enable or disable ?

Comment: @abdul its enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why its not worked is because of the case of module folders names.

Answer (score 0):

example for the script is

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$attributeSetId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("catalog_product", "costprice",  array(
        "type" => "int",
        "backend" => "",
        "label" => "Cost Price",
        "input" => "text",
        "source" => "",
        "visible" => true,
        "required" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique" => false,
        "note" => "Cost Price"
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", "costprice");

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $attributeGroupId,
        'costprice',
        '999'
);

$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

please check and compare

also check

> mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<modules>
    <Nie_Nie>
        <version>?.?.?</version>
    </Nie_Nie>
</modules>
```

Those should match for the script to run.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: this is not valid solution for module installation

Comment: i have give the solution for database because i am unable to access your code. hope you can understand.

Comment: but core_resource has not any records for this module then?

Comment: @abdul, yes, it does not have

Comment: Then in my install-1.0.0.0.php script simply runs this: simply put die('here'); on first line refresh page the script is running or not?

Comment: But module is not working then how to use your script ?

Comment: @denish-vachhani added line but nothing happends

Comment: than check packege_module.xml and check version number and script version number should be same. like mysql4-install-0.0.1.php than module virsion should be  <version>0.0.1</version>. and give 777 permission on all files.

Comment: it does not help